# Why does plymouth-quit-wait.service take me 3 minutes to enter my desktop?

Tags: systemd, plymouth

What does this thing do? It happens after I install a newer kernel, but it doesn't happen to another PC.

```
 3min 9.523s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      5.423s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.930s dev-sda1.device
      2.091s snapd.service
      1.612s dev-loop10.device
      1.602s dev-loop11.device
      1.581s dev-loop8.device
      1.574s dev-loop12.device
      1.534s dev-loop9.device
      1.299s dev-loop1.device
      1.263s dev-loop2.device
      1.239s dev-loop0.device
      1.232s dev-loop3.device
      1.218s dev-loop5.device
      1.191s udisks2.service
      1.179s dev-loop6.device
      1.175s dev-loop4.device
      1.159s dev-loop7.device
      1.099s ModemManager.service
      1.067s networkd-dispatcher.service
       948ms accounts-daemon.service
       888ms gdm.service
       857ms systemd-logind.service
       815ms avahi-daemon.service
       810ms thermald.service
       799ms loadcpufreq.service
       795ms gpu-manager.service
       772ms wpa_supplicant.service
       772ms NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: You can plot a graph and save that in a svg image using `systemd-analyze plot > output.svg`. You need to analyze this graph and determine which services are running in parallel and for which service plymouth is waiting.

Comment: I have done that before, but I don't see any service running in parallel with plymouth, I also don't know how to upload it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a bug in Ubuntu, I need to install `haveged` or `rng-tools` to fix it.

Comment: I would really appreciate a source for this statement.

Comment: Simply installing?  Isn't there more to it?

Comment: why would two random number generator packages have any affect on this boot time issue?